# Image gallery using div background url

Tags: jquery, css, image-gallery

When "#gallery is loaded, have the background image set to the first link in the list. "When "#trigger" is clicked, I want the background image of "#gallery" to be changed to the next sibling link. (Let me know if they should not be listed in the way that they are)

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="images/1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/2.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/3.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="trigger">Trigger</div>
```

I tried making a variable for the location of the link, and using it for the 
background of "#gallery" and then creating a click function event for "#trigger" where it changes the value of the variable to the next link.

This is my first post, so I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Image should be displayed as both `css` `background` of `#gallery` and at `img` element ? Or, only display single `img` element within `#gallery` element ?

Comment: I don't have the code anymore(wish I did) But on page load it set a variable that was the first link. Then it set the div background to that variable. Then when trigger was clicked it set the variable to the next link. (That's what it was supposed to do) I don't think I accomplished properly changing the variable or setting it as the background.

Comment: @BradChoiniere Should two images be displayed , or one ? Is "background" `css` `background` property ?, or actual `img` element which should cover entire `#gallery` `div` ?

Comment: The ul is set to display: none; The images are to be displayed as the div's background.

Comment: I made a variable using the ul li links. Then I used the variable as the url for the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of images and just change the url of the background-image applied to the div.

```
<div id="gallery">
</div>
<input type="button" id="trigger" value="Trigger">
<style>
#gallery
{
  background-image: url('/images/Image1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
var imageArr = ["/images/Image1.jpg"
                ,"/images/Image2.jpg"];
var slideIndex = 0; // sets the initial index
$('input:button').on("click",function()
{
  slideIndex++; // increment the index by 1 to get the next image
  if(imageArr.length <= slideIndex) // safe check - avoid index overflow and reset the index once reached the last image 
    slideIndex = 0;
  $("#gallery").css("background-image","url(" + imageArr[slideIndex] + ")");
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Sorry for the lack of detail on my post, and the basic nature of the question. I'm new to jQuery. You helped a lot! :)

Comment: No worries. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7yqu78eL/

A little sloppy but it should help you get the idea. Personally I wouldn't put my images as link hrefs. Just put them in a javascript array and save the hidden HTML - plus they will be easier to work with as an array.

Html

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-image-id="1" href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/"></a></li>
        <li><a data-image-id="2" href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/"></a></li>
        <li><a data-image-id="3" href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/abstract/"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="trigger">Trigger</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var currentImageId = 1;
  var totalImages = 3;

  rotateImage();

  $('#trigger').click(function() {
    rotateImage();
  });

  function rotateImage() {
    var url = $('#gallery').find('ul li a[data-image-id="'+currentImageId+'"]').attr('href');
    $('#gallery').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
    currentImageId++;
    if (currentImageId > totalImages) {
      currentImageId = 1;
    }
  }

});
```

CSS

```
#gallery {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#gallery ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with it as an array: https://jsfiddle.net/2c7z2qxq/ – much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using them as an array. I wasn't sure at first whether it would be ideal.